# GraphQL include multiple templates

Tags: jss, graphql

How to include multiple templates in GraphQL?

When I give something like below doesn't work.

```
children(includeTemplateIDs: "{614C6C64-AD35-440E-9668-DF39D8A18CCG},{B094FD0E-D349-46C0-B829-GBB37E8AB379}")
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the below format it works fine for me and most importantly it should be at the same level.

```
children(includeTemplateIDs: ["{614C6C64-AD35-440E-9668-DF39D8A18CCG}","{B094FD0E-D349-46C0-B829-GBB37E8AB379}"])
```

[image]

If you want inner child, you should add children query at the next level.

Comment: Thanks Gayathri. Let me try this in few cases then will confirm.